# Set width of svg using grunticon

Tags: css, svg, gruntjs

I am using svg with grunticon, and I want to set the hight and width to 100% of svg tag,I know that it can be done with js but can it be done by style or css or grunt options?
If is please add example

I am using the html like this:

```
<div class="icon-napoleon" data-grunticon-embed></div>
```

Comment: can you provide us with some of your code ?

Comment: Have you checked [this post on github](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon/issues/133)?

Comment: just using grunticon run it on my app and then from template html i amm using  <div class="icon-napoleon" data-grunticon-embed></div>  so I want to set for all svg the widht with hight to 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVG image is generated inside your `div` element, so the CSS should look like this:

```
.icon-napoleon,
.icon-napoleon svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Please note that **parent element must have width and height defined**. The only exception is when parent element is a block, than you do not need to set the `width` (it is 100% by default, still the height is required).

Comment: I insert this code and see it via styles window but from html insepct element I can see that the width and hight is not  set to 100%...

Comment: What is set instead? Can you copy-paste the CSS property that overrides the SVG width and height? Please also inspect the parent element and check its width and height values.

Comment: you was right! now one small q how can I added this style be with grunticon task?

Comment: I am really not familiar with grunticon, I just see the results. Hope someone else can help you.